# How to use a .a generated from MinGW in VS?

Tags: include, mingw, msys, .a

I´ve been searching with no success. Can I use the lib and include files generated using Msys in Visual Studio? If its possible, how? I have these programs I need to use in a GUI created in Visual Studio. I´ve already done this in Linux but I´m having problems trying to do the same but in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can by simply adding that `*.a` file to the link libraries, but I do not recommend doing so. You will very likely run into linker errors.

The better way is to generate a `*.dll` and an import library and then link against the import library.